# Python - Does a global variable in another imported module stay unique from other instances

Tags: python

If Module A is the main launcher and will import module B which has global data_set, will multiple instances have unique and separate data in memory?
My worry is, if I have several running instances of module A runing in different applications will the data in modules A & B affect each other?

If Process P and Process Q are both running module A, will the data in process P affect data in process Q?

I have no persistent data, it is all runtime.

Essentially, I have module B which is a utils file but several helper functions that depend on a global data cache (dictionary or list or w/e) that I pass along. I want make sure that when I run several different processes that they won't intermix because the variable namespaces are the same.

```
moduleA.py

import moduleB


def main():

   data = [x for x in range(100)]
   moduleB.dosomething(data)

moduleB.py

global data_cache = []


def function1(x):
   global data_cache

   data.cache.append(x)

def dosomething():

   fucntion1(data.cache.pop())
```

Comment: I can't tell if you are using `global` statements. If so, don't, there is always a better way. This question would be improved dramatically if you showed some code.

Answer (score 1):

Processes do not share process memory. Modules have independent yet persistent scopes within a single process. Importing a name from a module instead of the module itself makes a shallow copy of the object.

Comment: I normally concur totally with you, but I can't make sense of your last sentence. Yes, the OP was pretty ambiguous.

Comment: The last sentence (`from foo import bar`) probably doesn't pertain to the asker's situation.

Comment: I think you answer my question but I added some code for clarity.  What you think?

Comment: I think you don't understand what `global` does.

Comment: "Modules have independent yet persistent scopes within a single process"  What I was worried about is that on same machine if I'm running batch jobs and using hundreds of calls on the same module, I want that global variable to be unique to each process.

Comment: I didn't want to pass a parameter to helper functions.

Comment: Everything about a Python program is unique to that process except what you decide to explicitly make available to other processes through IPC or SHM.